# How can a client validate a OCSP Responders Delegate Certificate and how does it obtain it?

Tags: ocsp

In RFC 6960 [4.2.2.3.  Basic Response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6960#section-4.2.2.2) the response components are defined. This list does not contain the OCSP Responders certificate. If the responder is a delegate, the requester does not have a copy of the responders certificate up-front. How can it be able to validate the response and check for *id-kp-OCSPSigning* in the OCSP response signer's certificate?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the bullet list does not contain the certs. But directly underneath it is mentioned:

> The responder MAY include certificates in the certs field of
>   BasicOCSPResponse that help the OCSP client verify the responder's
>   signature.

And in **B.1.  OCSP in ASN.1 - 1998 Syntax**

```
BasicOCSPResponse ::= SEQUENCE {
  tbsResponseData          ResponseData,
  signatureAlgorithm       AlgorithmIdentifier,
  signature                BIT STRING,
  certs                [0] EXPLICIT SEQUENCE OF Certificate OPTIONAL }
```

Thus the answer to my question is: The client looks for a certificate in the *certs* list of the response that matches the ResponderID in either name or key hash:

> o  either the name of the responder or a hash of the responder's
>         public key as the ResponderID;

Then it validates the chain to verify that the response was signed by a trusted or authorized responder.

I found it helpful to review the [Verify existing OCSP Basic Response implementation in PKI.js](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/PKI.js/blob/master/src/BasicOCSPResponse.js#L482)